# Open pane temporarily with function key

Tags: key-bindings

I would like to have a workflow where I could make my <kbd>F9</kbd> key open up a shell in a split pane, and then have the same key effectively do a `C-x 0` on it. That way I could split, run a command, do some stuff, and go back to the file I was editing.

My attempt at this has some problems:

```
(defun split-shell-toggle ()
  (interactive)
  (split-window-below)
  (eshell))

(global-set-key (kbd "<f9>") 'split-shell-toggle)
```

In particular, I need to modify the function to check if the pane is visible, and then close the pane if it is. Right now I get this kind of thing:

[image]

It keeps splitting again and again. How can I check if the pane is already open, and close it if it is?

Comment: I would recommend creating a new function called `my-custom-eshell-function` by modifying the function `eshell` -- it is only a few lines long, and the key ingredient you will be modifying is `(pop-to-buffer-same-window buf)`.  And, here is your keyboard shourtcut:  `(global-set-key [f9] 'my-custom-eshell-function)`.  To find the source code of the function, you can use `M-x find-function RET eshell RET`  Instead of `pop-to-buffer-same-window`, you can use something better from the `window.el` library or create your own `display-buffer` function.

Comment: What do you want below the `*eshell*` buffer?  A `*scratch*` buffer perhaps?

Comment: You may interest in [shell-pop](https://github.com/kyagi/shell-pop-el).

Comment: @TuDo that is exactly what I'm looking for, want to make that an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may interest in [shell-pop](https://github.com/kyagi/shell-pop-el).